# Android Root Directory Rollback

Tags: android, linux, system, root, rollback

In an android tablet I am trying to make some changes, but whenever I make a change in root directory everything is rolling back to original, I even can't create a new directory at my `/` (root) directory, when I restart the device it is rolling everything back. What can I do about this?.

Comment: Have you got root permissions?

Comment: yes i have, i use adb shell then "su"

Comment: Actually I think this might help you http://android.stackexchange.com/a/112756/171172